# Mongoose retrieves null of my document inner array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection that one of it's fields is an array of strings. but when I query with `find()`, it returns `null` while in the MongoDB Compass I can see it.

here is my document:

```
{
   "_id":"5d4894f23f86a41b84303795",
   "position":1,
   "garmentTitle":"My first Garment",
   "garmentURL":"www.firstgarment.com",
   "garmentPictureURL":"/images/first.png",
   "brand":"5d49e60e4eface2a00ac58d7",
   "garmentMaker":"5d49e8854eface2a00ac58d9",
   "garmentPurpose":"5d49e8754eface2a00ac58d8",
   "gender":"5d37546f2f8c280adc60b3fe",
   "garmentCategory":"5d3a4c7f447a7a3afc71a746",
   "fabricComposition":null,
   "garmentSizes":["5d4d211f0fe9591facb9a268"] // <<== This is mentioned array
 }
```

Here is my defined schema :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var gardataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  position: {
    type: Number,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  garmentTitle: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  garmentURL: {
      type:String,
      required:false
  },
  garmentPictureURL: {
      type: String,
      required:false,
  },
  brand:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'BR',
    required: false
  },
  garmentMaker: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'GM',
    required: false
  },
  garmentPurpose: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'GP',
    required: false
  },
  garmentSizes: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'GS',
    required: false
  }],
  gender: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'GN',
    required: false
  },
  garmentCategory: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'GC',
    required: false
  },
  fabricComposition: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'FC',
    required: false
  },  
});

var collectionName = 'garmentData';
mongoose.model('GD', gardataSchema, collectionName);
```

And here is my controller:

```
module.exports.getOneGarmentDataByID = function (req, res) {
    GD.find({_id:req.params.id})
        .exec()
        .then(result => {
            res.status(200).json(result);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({error:err});
        });
}
```

Requested route:

```
http://localhost:3000/gar/getonegarmentdatabyid/5d4894f23f86a41b84303795
```

And final result is :

```
[
    {
        "garmentSizes": null, <<== returns null!!!
        "_id": "5d4894f23f86a41b84303795",
        "position": 1,
        "garmentTitle": "My first Garment",
        "garmentURL": "www.firstgarment.com",
        "garmentPictureURL": "/images/first.png",
        "brand": "5d49e60e4eface2a00ac58d7",
        "garmentMaker": "5d49e8854eface2a00ac58d9",
        "garmentPurpose": "5d49e8754eface2a00ac58d8",
        "gender": "5d37546f2f8c280adc60b3fe",
        "garmentCategory": "5d3a4c7f447a7a3afc71a746",
        "__v": 0,
        "fabricComposition": null
    }
]
```

As you can see it returns null instead of array object.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Schema type is wrong. Should be:

```
garmentSizes: {
    type: [
      {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: 'GS'
      }
    ],
    required: false
  }
```